# I am looking to add a scalebar to my ggmap in r, but keep getting "transform should be logical" error. How do iI fix this?

Tags: r

[image: Map I have successfully made (all tracks)]

```
alltracks+ ggsn::scalebar(x.min = -67, x.max = -66.5, 
                        y.min = 44.5, y.max = 44.6, 
                        dist = 5, dd2km = TRUE, 
                        model = "WGS84", height = 0.5, 
                        st.dist = 0.5)
```

**error:**

> Error in ggsn::scalebar(x.min = -67, x.max = -66.5, y.min = 44.5,
>   y.max = 44.6,  : transform should be logical.

I've tried changing the different elements but cannot find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 6):

I just stumbled on this same error. My plotting code that worked a year ago doesn't work now - it looks like `ggsn::scalebar` has been updated and requires a new argument `transform` instead of `dd2km`. `transform` must be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, otherwise you'll get this `transform should be logical` error. [ggsn::scalebar](https://github.com/oswaldosantos/ggsn/blob/master/R/scalebar.R) and its documentation need to be updated, since `transform = NULL` is the default and that throws this error (see lines 57-59).

Simply change `dd2km` to `transform` and you should be good:

```
alltracks+ ggsn::scalebar(x.min = -67, x.max = -66.5, 
                        y.min = 44.5, y.max = 44.6, 
                        dist = 5, transform = TRUE, 
                        model = "WGS84", height = 0.5, 
                        st.dist = 0.5)
```